# Searchable Spinner in Android With json file

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have a searchable spinner that contains the list of the client entered manually in a first place. Everything is working well.
First ,I add to gradle :  compile'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
then I create a fagment and a layout for testing searcheable spinner ,evrything work.
Now ,i 'd like to add a list of client by json file to my searchable spinner.
This is my code :

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class FicheHypothese1 extends Fragment {

SearchableSpinner spinner;

String Url="http://10.0.2.1/ODBC_Connect_INDUS/GET_CLIENTS.php";
public static List<String> lst=null;
private AdView mAdView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new GetData().execute();
    spinner= (SearchableSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner.setTitle("Countries");
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}


 class GetData extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        lst=new ArrayList<String>();
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                            try {
                                //Getting json object
                                JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                //Adding the name of the student to array list
                                lst.add(json.getString("CT_Intitule"));
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter adapter=new 
ArrayAdapter(getBaseContext(), 
R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, lst);
                        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        //Creating a request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = 
Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(movieReq);
        return null;
    }

}
```

}
and this is my layout:

```
<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
 </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my app was stoped
This is my log out :

```
04/12 17:48:22: Launching sample
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\stage2018\SearchableSpinner-master\sample\build\outputs\apk\sample-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.toptoche.sample
$ adb shell am start -n "com.toptoche.sample/com.toptoche.sample.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 10471 on device Nexus_6_API_27 [emulator-5554]
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/Ads: Required XML attribute "adSize" was missing.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.toptoche.sample, PID: 10471
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.toptoche.sample/com.toptoche.sample.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size and ad unit ID must be set before loadAd is called.
                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzab.zzdg(Unknown Source:16)
                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzab.zza(Unknown Source:4)
                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(Unknown Source:6)
                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(Unknown Source:0)
                      at com.toptoche.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
Application terminated.
```

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I dont get any error when I run the app crash

Comment: Nothing in the logcat?

Comment: I edit my post for more details

Comment: It actually has to do with the adView

Comment: on the `AdView` you have to set the `adSize` and `adUnitId` attribute in the layout file

Comment: thank you it work correctly now.

Comment: How can I delete the ad view and change my code .I mean I want to create a fragment now with the same context without ad view .

Comment: what do you mean? You want a fragment where the adView was?

Comment: Yes I dont have any idea where I can put the ad view in a fragment ?